# Replace string in a list if there are both , and ;

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a csv file (more than 2k lines, about 400kb) format as per the following example:

```
1,2,,test;test_A;test_B,ok,test;test_A,any
2,332,,test,ko,ok,test_A,any
2,567,,test_A;hello;test,ko,ok,any
```

and I have a dictionary object which maps the strings that should be replaced (keys: OLD value; values: NEW values):

`dict_items([('test', 'NOT_test'), ('test_B', 'XYZ_test_B')])`

How is possible to parse the entire file and replace all the occurrences?

I run a test with the following code:

```
for line in fileinput.input('myfile', inplace=True, backup='.bk'):
    for key,values in Changed_GRP_name_dict.items():
        print(line.replace(key, values), end='')
```

but the output create a 80Mb csv file ... `:-|`

Maybe the problems is relate with the presence of the ";", but I cannot remove it

Comment: please make your data format more readable

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: That format comes from another program, i cannot change it. Basically values can be separated by commas or semicolons (I cannot normalize it changing, for example, semicolons to commas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not combining all the replacements. You're doing each replacement separately to the original line, and showing the result of each of them.

Do all the replacements, updating `line` for each of them, and then print `line` once at the end.

```
for line in fileinput.input('myfile', inplace=True, backup='.bk'):
    for key,values in Changed_GRP_name_dict.items():
        line = line.replace(key, values)
    print(line)
```

Comment: OK, now it makes sense.
But i found some errors in replacement:
- test_A which should not be replaced is replaced too - maybe because I search for 'test'
- double replacement: for example NOT_test becames NOT_TestNOT_test
Maybe I need something to do an exact match :-|

Cheers,
--luciano

Comment: done a test with line = line.replace(re.compile('\\b'+key+'\\b'), values) but seems that regex is not supported with the replace function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple, really: instead of performing all the replacements on your line, and print the final result, you perform all replacements defined in `Changed_GRP_name_dict` on the original line you read from the file, each time replacing the values in the original line, and printing the result.

This way, you are printing `N * M` lines, if your input file had `N` lines and your replacements dictionary has `M` entries. It looks like `M` has about 20 replacements define in it - right?